# How to stop data transfers in GCP Project to external buckets?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a clear way to prevent data transfers in which a user in one of my projects executes a data transfer from one of our GCS buckets to a GCS bucket in their personal project?

I am familiar with VPC Service Controls but I’m not sure if there is a clear way to prevent egress data transfer, not only using the data transfer service, but also egress data movement via HTTP, SSH, and FTP protocols.

Comment: Revoke their access to the bucket?

Comment: In this case I’m talking about preventative measures for insider threats.

Comment: Please provide more information about the config. What permissions are required for the users? Do they have to be able to read the objects or simply write to those buckets?

Comment: A company can do the most to prevent insider threats by compensating employees appropriately and not engaging in ethically questionable behavior. Unfortunately, neither seems all that popular with top level executives. They're also probably outside your scope. You can do what you can do by limiting employees to only the access they need to do their jobs.